# Emails from specific sender not delivered to member of distribution list

Tags: email, office365, email-filter, google-workspace

I have a customer that has a Distribution List (DL) set up on their Outlook 365

They have added my email address, which is not a part of their organization, to that DL.
My email is part of a Google Workspace with a custom domain.

This setup used to work, however something changed and I have stopped receiving emails sent to this DL *from a specific sender* (which is also external to their organization)

Other similar emails from different organizations are delivered successfully (from external and the organization's domains)

Other members from within the organization of the DL **do receive all emails**

On my end I have a rule that any email sent to this DL should *not* be sent to spam, and I've also checked the [workspace quarantine](https://email-quarantine.google.com/adminreview) and the emails are not there.

Also, on their end they don't see any Delivery Failure Notice or other indication the forwarding failed.

Do you have any suggestions how to tackle this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @YisroelTech I did find the email in the [Email Log Search](https://admin.google.com/ac/emaillogsearch), it was sent from the organization's sender, and that's why I missed it initially.

The reason it is rejected is because of DMARC failure as it is "spoofing" the original sender: 550-5.7.26 Unauthenticated email. I believe the sender's DMARC record changed recently and that's what's triggered the failure

Attached a screenshot of a sample rejected email
[image: Rejected email screenshot]

Comment: Checked the [Email Log Search](https://admin.google.com/ac/emaillogsearch) in your Google Workspace?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this log, however unfortunately no results for that sender (which may increase the probability the problem is on their end?)

Comment: Yes. (Just make sure that the emails from other senders show in the log with the senders' address and not some mailing list address.)

Comment: Update! Thanks @YisroelTech I did find the email in the logs, it was from the organization's sender and that's why I missed it initially. The reason it is rejected is because of DMARC failure as it is "spoofing" the original sender: 550-5.7.26 Unauthenticated email. I believe the sender's DMARC record changed recently and that's what's triggered the failure? Suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Who's IP is the SMTP server IP (Google the IP for clues)? What seems like, is that the original sender's domain has a reject DMARC record set on their domain (they do) and the email is spoofed my Microsoft to send it to you modified from the mailing list.

Comment: Unsurprisingly its Microsoft's (  **.outbound.protection.outlook.com  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is something that plagues a lot of distribution list admins... (See for example [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2321576-distribution-group-to-external-senders-appear-to-be-spoofing-thus-are-blocked) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/889292/dmarc-on-prem-distribution-lists).) And to be honest I'm not sure whether a real solution exists.

The issue is fairly simple:

- The domain of the original (external) sender to the mailing list, email address for example is sender@domain1.com, has setup on their domain a DMARC Reject Policy (which basically tells whoever wants to listen to hard reject any messages from their domain that doesn't come from an IP address in their SFP. This more strict than a DMARC Quarantine Policy which would send it to Spam)
- The sender sends it to the distribution list, and the distribution list sends it out to all subscribers including those on external service, but the email is coming from the distribution list's org IP (or that of their mail provider) and it says it's coming from domain1.com
- Your email provider (Google Workspace) check the incoming message and since it fails the SFP check (IP isn't an allowed sender for this domain) and the domain has a Reject DMARC policy instruction it follows it and rejects the message

As for what can potentially be done/tried:

- <s>You on your end (in Google Workspace) maybe try adding this sender domain to the "approved senders list" (see https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368132?hl=en) but I'm not sure this will actually bypass a DMARC Reject policy failure</s> **Update:** *Confirmed by OP with Google support that this won't work in this case*
- The distribution list organization's admins can see what they can utilize to mitigate this (there are some methods, but it depends on their server's situation and not all of them actually work)
- If you have any say in the original sender's org, got can have them change the DMARC to Quarantine instead of Reject (generally quarantine should be enough to prevent spoofed mail from reaching users and Reject is an overkill... Perhaps have them review their DMARC reports to see how many legitimate emails from them fail for reasons like this or others)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it seems like it's not possible to have that domain whitelisted. I also confirmed this with Google Workspace support